# Distance in Kilometers with Parse.com geoPoint

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I need to calculate the distance in kilometers with Parse.com between one static geoPoint and another geoPoint, i now that there is a kilometersTo(point) function, but i really don't know how to use it. I have a function to call for my request like this:

```
distanceKms: function(objectId) {
        var query = new Parse.Query("empresa");
        return query.get(objectId, {
            success: function(object) {

            }
        });
    }
```

In the function above, i pass the ObjectId because i need to query my request and get the geoPoint, once i have it i want to calculate the distance between the static geoPoint and the objectId geoPoint.

Any help i will appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.GeoPoint.html#kilometersTo), you can pass it another `GeoPoint`. So in your case,

```
distanceKms: function(objectId) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("empresa");

    return query.get(objectId, {
        success: function(object) {
            console.log(object.kilometersTo(your_static_geopoint) + "kilometers");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick Reck, it works, i put this: console.log(object.get('location').kilometersTo(myStaticGeoPoint) + " kilometers");